# Add inline style to symfony2 twig form

Tags: css, twig, symfony-forms

```
{{ form_widget(titleForm.titleBasic, {'attr' : {'style' : { 'color:red', 'border:none' } }} ) }}
```

Sometime I had use inline css but I forggoted how to write twig sintax for inline css.

Comment: have you tried `{'style' : 'color:red, border:none'  }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me. With **;** instead of **,**

```
{{ form_widget(titleForm.titleBasic, {'attr' : {'style' : 'color:red; border:none' } }} ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old but still correct answer, I stumbled on it. A better and cleaner way to do this is to put your styling in the FormType:

```
        ->add('foo', TextType::class, [
        'attr' => [
            'style' => 'color:red, border:none',
            'placeholder' => 'Foo'
          ]
        ])
```

In that way if you use the form in other templates you wouldn't have to write extra inline css while rendering it.

Comment: Depends on where you want to manage your style. Adding style in FormType or in templates.